# Optimized Hibernate Query for Complex Objects

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to get just the mapping of `"a_Id, b_id, c_Id"` in an Object. What is the way using `Spring-Data-JPA` to get this? 
 
I have the following Table and Corresponding Entity(s).

```
Table A {                        Entity A {
    a_id,                              @Id pvt long aId;
    b_id,                              @ManyToOne
    c_id,                              @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
    a_field_1                          pvt B b;
                                       @ManyToOne
}                                      @JoinColumn(name="c_id")
                                       pvt C c;
                                       pvt String aField1;

Table B {                        Entity B {
    b_id,                              @Id pvt long bId;
    b_field_1,                         @OneToMany(mappedBy="b")
}                                      pvt A a;
                                       pvt String bField1;
                                 }
```

We can get the `b_id` and `c_id` individually using native queries. But we still need the mapping between A, B, C to be stored in object to know what values of C are associated with B.
I might be missing something very simple, but can't find a way w/o using `a.getB().getBId()`, which also implies individual queries for each `b_Id` will be executed, which I want to avoid, even though I've got `b_id`s through native query already. Also, I'm not keen using `FetchType.EAGER` on the `getB()`.
 Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code of how you have tried till now?

Comment: You can use DTO projections for this purpose, [follow this link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try **DTO projections** using a Constructor

Create  DTO class with constructor

```
class ABC {
    long aId,bId,cId, ...;
    public ABC( long aId, long bId, long cId, ...){
            //Set values here
    }
    //provide getters/setters
}
```

try Hibernate query as something

```
"select new " +
"   your.full.package.ABC(" +
"       a.aId, " +
"       b.bId, " +
"       c.cId, ..." +
"   ) " +
"from A a join a.b b join a.c c " +
"where some condition > :"
```